# boost::mpl for_each with normal 'C' Array

Tags: c++, boost, stl, boost-mpl

Using boost::mpl, I can create a typedef of a three element vector like follows:

```
typedef boost::mpl::vector_c<int,1,2,3> height_t;
```

I can pull the values out of this typedef with the following snippit:

```
std::vector<int> height;
boost::mpl::for_each<height_t>(boost::bind(&std::vector<int>::push_back, &height, _1));   

assert(height[0] == 1);
assert(height[1] == 2);
assert(height[2] == 3);
```

I'm wondering if there is a way to do this same thing but with a normal 'C' array instead of a `std::vector`.  Unfortunately, I can't use STL containers in this project.

```
uint32_t height[3];
boost::mpl::for_each<height_t>(????, &height, _1));
```

I suspect that I need to replace the ???? with another bind clause.  Any ideas?

Comment: This should not be tagged 'C'.  C and C++ are different languages.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like

```
 struct foo { 
     int c;
     int* arr;
     template<class U> 
     void operator(U& u) { arr[c++] = u; }
     foo(int a*) : c(0), arr(a) {}
 };

 for_each<height_t>(foo(height));
```

Comment: Taking the array by reference would be better then letting it decay to a pointer, e.g. `template<int n> struct foo { int (&arr)[n]; foo(int (&a)[n]) : arr(a) {} };`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your idea would work.  I rewrote it slighly.  However, what I am wondering is if there is a way to do this same thing with an inplace functor, using bind and lambda.  In the mean time, I'll use your idea.

```
template <typename type_t>
struct static_assign
{ 
    type_t* a;
    static_assign(type_t* a) : a(a) {}

    template<typename T> 
    void operator()(T t) 
    { 
        *a++ = t; 
    }
};

uint32_t color[MAX_COLORS];
uint32_t* pcolor = (uint32_t*)&color;
boost::mpl::for_each<typename static_color<scheme_t>::type>(static_assign<uint32_t>(pcolor));
pcolor += indicator;
```